# PHP's sem_acquire() - at what order do the 'waiting' processes get executed

Tags: php, semaphore, sysv-ipc

So semaphores in PHP are very convenient to synchronize jobs/tasks (process, to be more precise).

Say 1 process gains access to a semaphore and starts doing its thing (=work). 3 other processes are firing **sem_acquire()** to get access as well, at some order. They all get blocked, waiting for the semaphore to be free and assigned to each.

**Question is**: at what order will the 3 individual processes get executed? Common logic says that they'll get executed in first come (and gets blocked), first served (release to work), but I didn't see this statement in the official documentation.

Can anyone confirm or correct me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a script demonstrating, that YES, they are served on first-come first-serve basis. It was crucial for my app.

You can demonstrate it as well - create following [thread.php](https://www.codepile.net/pile/RnX8D7nd) and then call it using [this shell script](https://www.codepile.net/pile/EVe8G0xk).

UPDATE: [wikipedia for semaphores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)#:%7E:text=To%20avoid%20starvation%2C%20a%20semaphore%20has%20an%20associated%20queue%20of%20processes%20(usually%20with%20FIFO%20semantics).) explicitly mentions an associated **FIFO buffer** to avoid "starvation".

Comment: Do you think you could provide the script ? It could be useful for others.

Comment: I mean, can I post a zip here? 
Or take a look here:
Create this php script: https://www.codepile.net/pile/RnX8D7nd
and then run this shell script https://www.codepile.net/pile/EVe8G0xk

Comment: Thanks ! I think this might be worth it to edit your own answer and add the code for posterity :-).

Comment: I finaly figured out how to do it :) Done, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

The PHP `sem_acquire()` function calls through to the [`semop()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/semop) system call, which does not appear to make any guarantees regarding what order waiting processes will acquire a semaphore in.